# Importing data with multiple rows

Tags: sas

How would I import data using a data step with multiple rows? Example data:

```
Henry Grant
14523 Wicker Bag Street
Anaheim, CA 92461

Stuart Armstrong
632 Clam Juice Circle
San Luis Obispo, CA 93401

data Addresses;
    infile '/home/u60629206/SAS330_Handouts/Addresses.txt';
    input Name & $17.
    #2 Addresss $1-25
    #3 CityZip $1-26;
run;
```

It's not printing out my data correctly, only name variable coming out properly. Bit confused, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please post the code you've tried that has errors, and the log.

Comment: Why are you reading only three lines when your example appears to have four lines per person?  Also do all of the observations have exactly the same number of lines? Or do some include an extra address line?

Comment: There should be three lines, the fourth one should be empty just separating the different data observations. All the observations should have the same # of lines

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

- Add in & so that SAS looks for two spaces and doesn't truncate the variable
- Use / to indicate each line (instead of #2/#3)
- Specify lengths long enough for all the values
- Account for the break line in between (blank)
- You misspelled address (extra s)but not relevant to code

```
data Addresses;
    infile cards truncover;
    informat name address cityzip $50.;
    input Name &
    / Address  &
    / CityZip &
    / Blank;
cards;
Henry Grant
14523 Wicker Bag Street
Anaheim, CA 92461

Stuart Armstrong
632 Clam Juice Circle
San Luis Obispo, CA 93401

;;;;
run;
```